# ERROR: dav1d >= 0.2.1 not found using pkg-config

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, build, ninja, meson-build

I am trying to build ffmpeg with dav1d. I've successfully built davit using the following commands:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d.git && \
cd dav1d && \
mkdir build && cd build && \
meson .. && \
ninja
```

After that, I am running a config command for the FFmpeg and get the error:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/app/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
    --prefix="/app/ffmpeg_build" \
    --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
    --extra-cflags="-I/app/ffmpeg_build/include" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/app/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
    --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
    --bindir="/usr/local/bin" \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-libass \
    --enable-libmp3lame \
    --enable-libfreetype \
    --enable-libopus \
    --enable-libvorbis \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-libdav1d \
    --enable-nonfree
```

(All other libs are installed and FFmpeg configures and builds correctly with them if I omit `--enable-libdav1d`, but in case of the above command I get):

```
ERROR: dav1d >= 0.2.1 not found using pkg-config
```

I think the reason could be that meson puts bin files in the wrong directory. Could anyone please help?

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Example of build commands for the other libs:

```
git -C x264 pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264.git && \
cd x264 && \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/app/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="/app/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="/usr/local/bin" --enable-static --enable-pic && \
make && \
make install
```

Comment: Missing path to the "package config file" = dav1d.pc : Assume `sudo ninja install` to **/usr/local/** .... You can do  `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/dav1d.pc  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/` .... Or copy  from `dav1d/build/meson-private/dav1d.pc`

Comment: `sudo ninja install` made the trick. Thanks, Knud!

Answer (score 3):

To pass the build you have to add `ninja install`:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d.git && \
cd dav1d && \
mkdir build && cd build && \
meson --bindir="/usr/local/bin" .. && \
ninja && \
ninja install
```

But this not enough, if you run FFmpeg after, you'll get:

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libdav1d.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To fix this issue add `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=":/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Comment: you could also add `--default-library=static` in the `meson` call and avoid updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`